# How can I automatically flag an email after reply in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, power-automate

I would like to see if there is any way that anyone replies in a shared mailbox to any email and the email is automatically flagged in outlook. Can be via Power Automate or VBA.

Comment: So then why don’t you do it?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant shared mailbox. I do not have the solutions for it

Comment: What have you tried so far? You question needs more clarification.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a reminder to the message when you reply to it?

Comment: Something like that... In outlook, we have a feature to flag emails or categorize emails.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you would need to set the `MailItem.Categories` property and/or `MailItem.ReminderSet` / `ReminderTime` properties on the original item in the folder.

You can use `Explorer.SelectionChange` event to track the item selection, set up `MailItem.Reply/ReplyAll` event handlers on the item(s) from the `Explorer.Selection` collection, and then set the reminder properties in the event handler. Or you can use `Explorer.InlineResponse` event to set up the properties on the first item in the `Explorer.Selection` collection